# Library finvizfinance: how to work with USA industries

Tags: python, finance, yfinance

I can't write good python code. My target is the following:

a) ask about three first usa industries for mean yield 30 days rolling

b) create a dynamically list of ticker components of first three industries with the fields:

- ticker
- industries
- sector

c) export all data in excel

i need your help for a) and b)

my code is:

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
from finvizfinance.screener.overview import Overview

# Define a function to fetch historical stock data for a given ticker symbol
def get_stock_data(ticker):
    stock = yf.Ticker(ticker)
    return stock.history(period="30d")["Adj Close"]

# Define a function to get the sector and industry for a given ticker symbol
def get_sector_and_industry(ticker):
    stock_info = Overview()
    stock_info_stock = stock_info.ticker_data(ticker)
    return stock_info_stock["Sector"], stock_info_stock["Industry"]

# Define a function to calculate the mean yield for a sector over the last 30 days
def calculate_mean_yield(tickers):
    sector_mean_yield = {}
    for ticker in tickers:
        sector, _ = get_sector_and_industry(ticker)
        if sector not in sector_mean_yield:
            sector_mean_yield[sector] = []
        data = get_stock_data(ticker)
        mean_yield = (data[-1] - data[0]) / data[0] * 100
        sector_mean_yield[sector].append(mean_yield)
    return {sector: sum(yields) / len(yields) for sector, yields in sector_mean_yield.items()}

# Define a list of stock tickers to analyze
stock_tickers = ["AAPL", "MSFT", "GOOGL"]  # You can add more tickers as needed

# Fetch data, calculate mean yields, and get sector and industry info
mean_yields = calculate_mean_yield(stock_tickers)

# Create a DataFrame for the results
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Ticker": stock_tickers,
    "Sector": [get_sector_and_industry(ticker)[0] for ticker in stock_tickers],
    "Industry": [get_sector_and_industry(ticker)[1] for ticker in stock_tickers],
    "Mean Yield (%)": [mean_yields[get_sector_and_industry(ticker)[0]] for ticker in stock_tickers]
})

# Create the Excel file with a unique name
from datetime import datetime
current_date = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
excel_file_name = f"STUDY_{current_date}.xlsx"

# Save the data to the Excel file
df.to_excel(excel_file_name, index=False)

print(f"Data exported to {excel_file_name}")
```

If you suggest complete new code you will be welcome. I wanna study deeply this library and I wanna write in future a guide.